# How to escape a backslash in the end to mean literal backslash in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, escaping, gnu-make, backslash

Here is my Makefile:

```
SLASH = \

all:
    echo '$(SLASH)'
```

This is the output:

```
$ make all
echo ''

$
```

The `\` in the end means line continuation in `Makefile`, so it ends up assigning an empty string into `SLASH`.

How can I assign a literal backslash into `SLASH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably use a dummy `blank' to fool `make`...

```
BLANK :=
SLASH = \$(BLANK)

all:
    echo '$(SLASH)'
```

The above gives me...

```
G.M> make -f how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-the-end-to-mean-literal-backslash-in-makefile.mk
echo '\'
\
G.M>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is additional `$ #` at the end of line:

```
SLASH = \$ #

all:
    @echo '$(SLASH)'
```

Similar trick is described in `make` manual [3.1.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Lines.html#Splitting-Without-Adding-Whitespace).